# Create Json using Flight php

Tags: php, json, flightphp

I have a problem where I have to create a JSON using `Flight::json`.
I have an array, called `$data`, that contains some elements like

```
  $data[] = array('id'=>$temp,'type'=>'remote','url'=>$path);
```

where $id and $path have different values like this:

```
[id] => http://desktop-pqb3a65:8080/marmotta/resource/22086372-476f-4974-b538-64019ab678b3
[url] => D:\Software\Marmotta\marmotta-home\resources\1d\4d\ea\1d4dea13-f8e6-4cf0-b96a-f88b08efda2b
```

When I try to convert that in a JSON using:

```
Flight::json($data);
```

my PHP page returns me this format instead:

```
{"id":"http:\/\/desktop-pqb3a65:8080\/marmotta\/resource\/22086372-476f-4974-b538-64019ab678b3","type":"remote","url":"D:\\Software\\Marmotta\\marmotta-home\\resources\\1d\\4d\\ea\\1d4dea13-f8e6-4cf0-b96a-f88b08efda2b"}
```

I read the documentation and I tried to convert using another function:

```
Flight::json($data, $code = 200, $encode = false, $charset = 'utf-8');
```

but it return an error like:

```
500 Internal Server Error
Array to string conversion (8)
```

So can you help me to convert `$data` without this type of error? I must use `Flight` to convert my array.

Thanks all for help!

**EDIT**

I solve my problem creating a function like this:

```
Flight::map('jsonc', function($obj, $status = 200) {
Flight::response()
    ->status($status)
    ->header('Content-Type', 'application/javascript')
    ->write(utf8_decode(json_encode($obj, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)))
    ->send();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want unescaped slashes I believe you can pass that as the 5th function parameter named `$option`, see [source](https://github.com/mikecao/flight/blob/master/flight/Engine.php#L468).

```
public function _json(
        $data,
        $code = 200,
        $encode = true,
        $charset = 'utf-8',
        $option = 0
    )
```